# How do I schedule a task with in a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm a new dev and I'm currently working on a discord bot for my class' server. It's supposed to constantly check for any changes in our Google Calendar.

What can I do to check our google calendar for example for every second.

I've tried the apscheduler module and i keep on getting traceemalloc (?) errors as well as runtime errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the docs for [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/). Here is an example of how you would check your calendar every 15 seconds:

```
from discord.ext.tasks import loop

@loop(count=None, seconds=15)  # Run forever, check every 15 seconds.
async def check_calendar():
    # Your code for checking calendar here
    
    
@check_calendar.before_loop
async def before_check_calendar():
    await client.wait_until_ready()  # Wait until bot is ready.

check_calendar.start()
client.run("bot_token")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! I'll try it out!

Comment: Just a follow-up question, let's say the bot sees that there's something new and wants to send a message to the channel. Should I place the send outside the loop?

Comment: It should be inside the loop.